# Random windows & application switching between monitor when multiple monitors go to sleep

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

TL;DR Is there a way to delay the window manager automatically moving applications to active monitors when one of multiple monitors turns off? I'm running KDE.

I'm running Kubuntu 22.04. I have a problem with all of my applications sometimes (only sometimes, not all the time) shifting to a single monitor. This can happen when the screen saver comes on and the monitors turn themselves off for low-power saving mode. I don't know exactly why but I have a guess. It's never happened before when I only had two monitors. But recently I added a third monitor and it is a different brand.

The two same brand model monitors shut down at essentially the same time. But the third monitor shuts down about five or six seconds later. Could this be causing delay which triggers the window-manager to shift all of my open windows/applications to the last remaining display? (If that is the case, is there a way to delay this?)

If my guess is wrong, does anyone else know why my applications randomly seem to all switch to the third monitor during sleep and wake up?

Comment: This yet requires an answer. I am facing this for a 4 monitor setup and need a solution. Any help is appreciated.